# Android - extending setOnGroupExpandListener method

Tags: android, listener, expandablelistview

I am using an ExpandableListView. It works fine, but I want to add an OnGroupExpandListener;
The problem is if I override it, the 'basic' default behaviour for that is overridden as well. I basically want something like this:

```
        mTeamListAdapter = new TeamListAdapter(getLayoutInflater());
        mTeamList =  (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.screen_team_teamslist);
        mTeamList.setAdapter(mTeamListAdapter);
        mTeamList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        mTeamList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                // do my stuff..
                // something like "super();" to enable the other default behaviour  
            }

        });
```

Specifically, I want to make a Button visible (and clickable - it is `"android:visibility="gone"` before) on each group in the ExpandableListView. I still want each group, and its children, to be clickable as well!
How do I do this?

EDIT: By "basic default behaviour", I mean that if I override that method (OnGroupExpand) it seems I cannot expand/collapse the groups anymore!

Comment: nothing should be affected by setting the `OnGroupExpandListener`!! Weird. 
Anyway, try to `setGroupIndicator` using a non-null value?

Answer (score 0):

The assertion that "the 'basic' default behaviour is overridden" when an `OnGroupExpandListener` is set is not correct.

You can verify it by looking at the source code for `ExpandableListView` (see the `handleItemClick` method):

http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/ExpandableListView.java&q=package:android.git.kernel.org%20file:android/widget/ExpandableListView.java&l=1

Are you sure you haven't set a `OnGroupClickListener`? This WILL override group expansion if its `OnGroupClick` implementation returns true (i.e. the click is deemed to be handled).

Either that, or something in your specific `OnGroupExpand` implementation is affecting the data that your `ExpandableListAdapter` uses to display the child rows for the groups.